# How to make MySQL value Increase by one, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following database table.

```
 id     article_content       article_views
   1       content..             48
```

I am trying to increase the value of the column `article_views` using mysql query.

I know I can fetch the number and then add +1 and then update the value, but is there any better way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: tried article_views = article_views+1  ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query becomes -

```
Update TABLE_NAME SET article_views = article_views+1 WHERE id = 'your_id'
```